# Can I specify fileloggerparameters in msbuild project file

Tags: msbuild

I see that you can use the /**fileLogger** and /**fileloggerparameters** command line arguments in msbuild to specify things like the location of the log file. Is there any way to specify this information in the Project or PropertyGroup section of the project file?  I have all my other project properties imported via an include file.  I really don't want to have to one set of properties in an include file and then another set that is specified on the command line.

Comment: the logging parameters are really about msbuild not the the project.  What you could always do is use one msbuild file to kick off another with the correct log level.

Comment: @rerurn you should post that as an answer, seems like the only valid answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware just VC projects has ability log build into separate files. But you have  to build it through devenv :-(
and you don't have control over other logging parameters.

Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <BuildLog>
    <Path>$(IntDir)\$(MSBuildProjectName).log</Path>
  </BuildLog>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Other ugly way is to execute build of each project via

```
<Exec Command="msbuild.exe  project /fl /flp...." />
```

I guess you want to avid it.

I'm think it could be possible to create custom [distributed file logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651795.aspx) to do this but I sill don't have it working properly.